# Issue with starting X session and tmux, "bad substitution"

Tags: bash, ubuntu, x11, tmux, window-managers

When I log-in with the GDM, choosing any option (Currently, there are three options Ubuntu, XMonad and EXWM) the session doesn't properly starts.

If I go to another tty, the terminal starts with the message:

```
-bash: $PATH:${$(find ~/.local/bin -type d -printf %p:)%%:}: bad substitution
unsetopt: command not found
\033[31mIMPORTANT\033[0m: Note that \033[32m`libxft-bgra`\033[0m must be installed for this
build of dwm.
  Please run:
          \033[32myay -S libxft-bgra-git\033[0m
  and replace `libxft`. Afterwards, you may start the graphical server by running `startx`.
```

Note: I have no ideia where this message comes from. Not from my `.bashrc` for sure. And, I'm not using `DWM`, only `st`.

Anyways, that same message appears when I try to run `tmux`.

The problem `startx` problem started right after the `tmux` issue happened.

Any idea of what files may be loaded, when this happens?

**OBS: I already have libxft-bgra rightfully installed. It has nothing to do with the problem, as far as I know (emojis are being rendered correctly on the terminal).**

Comment: Well, ends up that I was using EXWM, and tangled some old configs that used `.profile`, from `zsh`. And that messed up the initial configs of bash, tmux, and startx (I don't have zsh installed currently etc.)